# If gravitational waves exist. Do anti gravitational waves exist

Tags: science

If gravitational waves exist. Do anti gravitational waves exist. And could they also be detected using a liegar detector. And if gravitional waves exist when 2 masses are combined e.g two black holes. Does this apply to super nova for anti gravitational waves as mass is being separated from one another.
Is space itself,  anti gravity as space is expanding. Or an exploding star for example anti gravity. Is this the answer?

Comment: Hi @john there are almost [200 Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) and it's sometimes hard to judge where to ask a question. Questions about gravitational waves are best asked and answered in [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) or [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) rather than here in Space Exploration. I think your question will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to all of us. The quickest way to proceed is for you to 1) check Physics SE or Astronomy SE to make sure your exact question hasn't been asked already, 2) if not, post your question there, 3) delete it here since it is discouraged to ask the same question in multiple sites. Good luck and *Welcome to Space!*